# PHP DateTime diff issue between dates

Tags: php

```
$start = new DateTime('2014-01-07', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$end = clone $start;
$start->sub(new DateInterval('P1M')); // substract one month

echo $start->format('Y-m-d').' - '.$end->format('Y-m-d');
// 2013-12-07 - 2014-01-07 - seems correct, let's get number of days...

print_r($end->diff($start));
// DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 2 [d] => 0 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [invert] => 1 [days] => 61 )
```

61 days??? What is going on in here?

Comment: What do you want ? not clear at all.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman I'm subtracting 1 month and get 61 days in diff().

Comment: That is definitely odd. I can't replicate the problem. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Running that on [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/iK0tH) suggests that this is a glitch that was present in 5.3.0 through 5.3.2 only.

Comment: I'm on 5.3.2 :( @DCoder thanks for introducing me to 3v4l.org :)

Comment: @DCoder great site, bookmarked!

Comment: Do you want only days i difference or complete date like new will be `2013-12-07` ?

Comment: [Bug #51184](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184) and [Bug #52480](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52480)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is un-fixable (PHP bug)

Comment: Thanks Phil, time to upgrade ;)

Comment: @marcin_koss Yeah. By voting to close, I didn't mean this wasn't a good question (it is) but the answer really is simply *"upgrade PHP"* which isn't really a good StackOverflow answer

Comment: I understand although (just thinking out loud) maybe it will give answer to others who discovered the same issue ;)

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```